# True java generics (templates)

Tags: java, templates, generics, classloader

After taking a look in the [Java VM specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#25310), I noticed that a lot more than just ASCII letters could be used to create an identifier.

Firstly, I was wondering if there were any extra symbols (apart from `$`, that are available for identifiers)

Do you think it would be possible, with the extended character set to encode additional information in an identifier, and a custom classloader, to implement true Java generics?

Of course, you would have to get around type erasure, but that could be possible with a custom parser?

So you could store generic names in a format like: `$g$GenericList$_Java_lang_String$`

I'm using `GenericList` here as I don't intend to modify the original implementation!

Load them in with the class loader, create a proper `GenericList<String>` version and send it back.

**EDIT:** I plan to use this for a language I'm building on the JVM. As it uses `$`'s and `_`'s as special characters, encoding information like that might just work!

**EDIT 2:** I suppose the more difficult thing to do would be generic methods? Does anyone have any information on how those would be implemented?

**EDIT 3:** Since classes can only be unloaded when the classloader disappears, would I be able to cache and remove resolved templates like it works in .Net, or would I do it like C++?

Comment: +1, interesting idea. Be sure to have a look at the .NET IL, which uses a similar concept to implement generics without type erasure (there, the character ` (backtick) is used to delimit generic parameters in identifiers).

Comment: I've actually been looking at Rotor (SSCIL), very very interesting. My problem is more how I'd implement the caching and time-to-live of each generic isntance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM allows any characters in class/field/method names except `/`, and `;` which have a special meaning. Using numbers and other character is common for obfuscators to make de-compiling difficult.

However you could just use the `$` and `_` for generated class/fields/methods.

Note: JDK 7 is supposed to have better generic support with the `Type` with a combination of Class and generics.

EDIT:

One way to have proper generic type is to always use

```
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>() { };
```

The use of `{ }` creates an anonymous class which has a parent type with the generic you want. You can get this information via reflection.

You can cache and remove class by having your own class loader which you dispose of as you wish. The most extreme case would be to have a ClassLoader per class.

Once you have your own Generic types, you could just use these in your methods, like normal types.

Comment: Very interesting...opens a good range of possibilities! Unfortunately, I can't rely on clients having Java 7, so I have to work with what I have for the being

Comment: Very interesting on the `{ }` front! Do you know if it's possible to move classes between classloaders?

Comment: You can use classes from several class loaders at once. You can load the same class (name and behaviour) into multiple class loaders but once a Class is loaded by a class loader, it cannot be moved.  You can have other class loaders use this class however.

Comment: Type checking is done by the compiler. It would work the same as it does now.  The only thing it would add is the ability to get the generic type information at runtime. (Which you cannot do otherwise)

Comment: So if I wanted to prune off certain resolved templated classes, I could create a new classloader. load in the ones I want to stay, and dereference the previous one?

Comment: Why on earth aren't people aware of this trick! are there any downsides of it?

Comment: Yes, that would work provided you removed all references and they were GCed.

Comment: Because it not very useful in most situations I imagine. Never found a use for it myself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you can use Unicode you can basically use everything except the few letters mentioned in the previous answer (/,;).
There is nothign like "true generics" btw ... I know what you mean ;D and that is called "Templates".

Comment: It's terrible I know, I was thinking that it might be possible to do a basic workaround though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use any unicode character as identifier name in java. See [**here**](http://k2java.blogspot.com/2011/04/identifier-in-java.html) for identifier names allowed in java. But as mentioned in previous answer, you mean "templates" for "true generics".